# Not able to modify headers in chrome extension using `declarative_net_request` 's `rule_resources` for websockets

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, websocket, http-headers, chrome-declarativenetrequest

I am trying to modify origin header in a websocket creation process in a chrome extension.
I have `declarativeNetRequestWithHostAccess` in permissions.
I am trying to use a rule of type `modifyHeaders`.
**It perfectly modifies the headers for `fetch()` calls but not for websockets.**
What am I missing?

Here is the rule ie src/rules/example.json:

```
[
  {
    "id": 2,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": {
      "type": "modifyHeaders",
      "requestHeaders": [
        {
          "header": "origin",
          "operation": "set",
          "value": "https://www.example.ai"
        },
        {
          "header": "referer",
          "operation": "set",
          "value": "https://www.example.ai"
        }
      ]
    },
    "condition": {
      "urlFilter": "example",
      "isUrlFilterCaseSensitive": false,
      "resourceTypes": ["xmlhttprequest", "websocket"]
    }
  }
]
```

Here is manifest.json

```
...
...
  "declarative_net_request": {
    "rule_resources": [
      {
        "id": "ruleset_example",
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "src/rules/example.json"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: Apparently your host_permissions don't include ws:// and wss:// protocols.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have same rule set for another website ie `"resourceTypes": ["xmlhttprequest", "websocket"]` it works fine there. and I have this in manifest.json `optional_host_permissions: ['https://*/*', "wss://*/*"],` . Maybe I am missing something which I did for the other site.

Comment: Maybe the site is using ws: and not wss:. Maybe your rule's urlFilter doesn't match the URL used by the site. Maybe you didn't grant these permissions to the other site, which you can verify via chrome.permissions API.

Comment: @wOxxOm moving "wss://*/*" from `optional_host_permissions` to `host_permissions` solved it. I guess for `optional_host_permissions` I would have to do `chrome.permissions.request({ origins: ['wss://example.com'] })` as well which I was not doing. Meanwhile I have another issue , please visit my profile's latest question let me if you can help on it.

Comment: @ishandutta2007 did you do anything else? I also try to modify origin for websocket, but failed

Comment: @Viewed no for me `host_permissions: [....,"wss://*/*"]` was the solution.Every other step I mentioned in question. This was the only missing piece. I was sure I didn't need `"ws://*/*"` so I didn't but as wOxxOm pointed out you might need that in case your websocket makes over `ws`. the reason fetch was working because `"https://example.com"` was already added in `host_permissions`

Comment: @ishandutta2007 are you making wss request from background script ? i try your solution in background script, but no lucky.

Comment: @NewBee no foreground ie content-script

Comment: in content-script, how you can make a cors-domain request.

Comment: @NewBee read `declarative_net_request `

Comment: @NewBee I would suggest you create a new question if this doesn't answer your problem. Everything done has been covered above either in the question or in wOxxOm's solution.

Answer (score 0):

As @wOxxOm mentioned,

moving `"wss://*/*"` from `optional_host_permissions` to `host_permissions` solved it.

I guess for `optional_host_permissions` I had to call `chrome.permissions.request({ origins: ['wss://example.com'] })` as well which I was not doing.