# how to modify header in chrome extension for wss request with background script

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have try the solution provided in question [modify header in chrome extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77050926/not-able-to-modify-headers-in-chrome-extension-using-declarative-net-request), the declarative_net_request rules solution works in chrome-extension://extension-id/some-page and normal html page, but not work in background script(service_worker), after test, background script can modify https|http header, but can not modify wss.

Now, my question is how to modify header in chrome extension for wss request with background script. why wss header can not be modified in background script.

Comment: @wOxxOm may you kindly help me on this.